# Necessity and Possibility, Domain Widen, Indeterminate Phrase

Tags: semantics, pragmatics, formal-semantics, logic

I wanna ask a question about semantics. It's on page 20 in the paper "Indeterminate Pronouns: The View from Japanese" (Kratzer & Shimoyama, 2002).

What I don't understand is the part Computing the total meaning of (17). Why is N(A)↔N(B) (N stands for necessity, I guess) equal to P(A) & P(B)?

And doesn't N(A)↔N(B) mean "must borrow A iff must borrow B and vice versa"? In this case, isn't it the case that the person has to borrow both (which is not the intended meaning of the sentence)?

Thx in advance!

Below is the text:

Necessity

(17) Du musst dir irgendeins von diesen beiden Büchern leihen.
You must you(dat.) irgend-one of those two books borrow. ‘You must borrow one of those two books, it doesn’t matter which.’

Alternative set chosen: Must {A, B}.

T(ruth-conditional) content: N(A∨B)

Figuring out the implicature

She picked the widest set of alternatives, {A,B}. Why didn’t she pick {A}, which would have led to a stronger claim? It might be that N(A) is false. Or else, it might be that N(A) is true, but its exhaustivity inference ¬N(B) is false. We infer N(A)→N(B). The same kind of reasoning can be given for why she didn’t pick {B}, and we infer N(B)→N(A).

Computing the total meaning of (17)

N(A∨B) T-content of claim

N(A)↔N(B) Implicature

N (A∨B) & (N(A)↔N(B)) Total meaning

N (A∨B) & P(A) & P(B) Implication of total meaning